# Regex Pattern for below url

Tags: regex, logstash-grok

Can someone give regex pattern for below example url ?

https://test.example.com/new/index.html?token=0A44AD94

If there is a possibility to split up the field, then I could easily populate those value for monitor each user activity.

Comment: This is for those who downgrade this question,. Don't you have time to update the comment here , why its downgrade .?

Comment: what did you try so far? post your attempts!

Comment: we cannot edit the question, because we don't know what you tried already.

Comment: Try `^.*?://(?<domain>[^/]*).*\btoken=(?<token>[^&]*).*\bvalue=(?<value>[^&]*).*\bexit=(?<thirdparty>[^&]*)`.

Comment: @stribizhev thanks for your reply. I have tried it on this url "http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/" . it says "No Maches".

Comment: @KMG: That tool seems buggy: I have also used it to write the regex, and upon closing/reopening the page and pasting the regex back, I also see No Matches. When you manually remove the last pranethetical part, and type it by hand, you will get a match.

Comment: Yes, it shows. Is there any alternate tool to validate the regex pattern ?, as i was trying this out on this url " "grokdebug.herokuapp.com/"

Comment: Also one more help, is there any possible to use the same regex pattern for the below possibility ?
https://test.example.com/new/index.html?token=0A44AD94&value=80f455c5-dbda-4330
here, I have excluded "3rd party section". so this part may or may not comes in the request. Can you please do me a favor and do alternate the same regx to compatible for both case ?.
case 1 : https://test.example.com/new/index.html?token=0A44AD94&value=80f455c5-dbda-4330
https://test.example.com/new/index.html?token=0A44AD94&value=80f455c5-dbda-4330&exit=https://www.demo-test.com/site_xin_redirect/

Comment: You can try using optional non-capturing groups: `https?://(?<domain>[^/]*).*\btoken=(?<token>[^&]*).*\bvalue=(?<value>[^&]*)(?:.*\bexit=(?<thirdparty>[^&]*))?`. I do not know which site is best to test Grok regexps, this one you are using seems OK, just there's this glitch.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Your solution solved my problem. If you reply the same on "Post Answer". I will set it to correct answer.  Also can you please share some regex online tutorial for beginners [ Either video or Docs] ? .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87769/discussion-between-kmg-and-stribizhev).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex to match those kinds of URLs with optional third-party component and where params *always* follow the fixed order:

```
https?://(?<domain>[^/]*).*\btoken=(?<token>[^&]*).*\bvalue=(?<value>[^&]*)(?:.‌​*\bexit=(?<thirdparty>[^&]*))?
                                                                            ^^                             ^^
```

Note that `[^/]*` matches 0 or more characters other than `/`, `[^&]*` matches 0 or more characters other than `&` (which is helpful when matching param values in the query string so as not to overmatch). `(?:...)?` is an optional non-capturing group that can be present or not, but the regex will still succeed.

**UPDATE:**

After checking a few things, I think this regex will work for you:

```
%{IPORHOST:clientip} (%{USER:ident}|-) (%{USER:auth}|-) \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] (?:%{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|%{DATA:rawrequest})" %{NUMBER:response} (?:%{NUMBER:bytes}|-) "%{URIPROTO}://(?<domain>[^/]*).*[&?]token=(?<token>[^&]*).*[&?]value=(?<value>[‌​^&]*)(?:.*[&?]exit=(?<thirdparty>[^"&]*))?"(?:\s*%{QS:agent})?
```

For some reason, `{QS:agent}` already includes double quotation marks.

Comment: If you add your own previous attempts (at least one), it would be very good.

Comment: one more doubt, Above example is working fine when its match with referrer url. But when I check the same along with userAgent, its says "No Matches". 

Example url format :
"https://test.example.com/new/index.html?token=0A44AD94&value=80f455c5-dbda-4330&exit=https://www.demo-test.com/site_xin_redirect/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/39.0.2171.65 Chrome/39.0.2171.65 Safari/537.36"

Please share the pattern match for the above sample format. Also Please share some good tutorial to learn regex pattern.

Comment: The online tester says `https?://(?<domain>[^/]*).*[?&]token=(?<token>[^&]*).*[?&]value=(?<value>[^&]*)(?:.*[?&]exit=(?<thirdparty>[^&]*))?` is working. The best tutorials are [Regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) and [rexegg.com](http://rexegg.com).

Comment: I added a regex that captured `{QS:agent}` in my tests.

Comment: Yes, its working fine. But log parsing is very slow with this pattern. Single log request is taking around 3 sec to parse. Do you have any chance to check it .?.

Comment: No wonder, it has mega lots of subpatterns that we do not have control over. Perhaps, we can use atomic groups, but I do not know if they work with Grok. I will update you once I check that.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Are you able to see the last day chat windows.? . if it so , then we can continue our discuss there. 

http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87769/discussion-between-kmg-and-stribizhev

Comment: any chance to check this ?.

Comment: Try `%{IPORHOST:clientip} (%{USER:ident}|-) (%{USER:auth}|-) \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] (?:%{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?> HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|%{DATA:rawrequest})" %{NUMBER:response} (?>%{NUMBER:bytes}|-) "%{URIPROTO}://(?<domain>(?>[^/]*).*[&?]token)=(?>(?<token>[^&]*).*[&?]value)=(?<value>[‌​^&]*)(?>.*[&?]exit=(?<thirdparty>[^"&]*))?"(?>\s*%{QS:agent})?`. It works, but I do not know if it is any faster.

Comment: the above format says, "Compile Error" .

below pattern is reason behind for Compile Error, Can you please check and provide the correct one to test ?

"%{URIPROTO}://(?<domain>(?>[^/]*).*[&?]token)=(?>(?<token>[^&]*).*[&?]value)=(?‌​<value>[‌​^&]*)(?>.*[&?]exit=(?<thirdparty>[^"&]*))?"

Comment: any chance to check .? I think, I made some mistake when parsing above given pattern.

Comment: Try `(?>%{IPORHOST:clientip} (%{USER:ident}|-) (%{USER:auth}|-) \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] (?:%{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|%{DATA:rawrequest})" %{NUMBER:response} (?:%{NUMBER:bytes}|-) "%{URIPROTO}://(?<domain>[^/]*).*[&?]token=(?<token>[^&]*).*[&?]value=(?<value>[‌​^&]*)(?:.*[&?]exit=(?<thirdparty>[^"&]*))?"(?:\s*%{QS:agent})?)`